# reformat date into a numeric MDY value in MySQL

Tags: mysql, date, date-format

I have a column in a table that has dates, as such:

```
2010-01-15 00:00:00
2002-10-24 09:00:00
2015-04-29 10:00:00
```

and now I need to generate a new column as such (month, date, year):

```
01152010
10242002
04292015
```

I can't find an easy way to do this. All the solutions I've looked at are either for changing date type or getting seconds since epoch!

I've also tried all sorts of substring operations

Answer (score 4):

You could try using the [MySQL DateFormat Function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format).

The documentation is pretty a good resource for this sort of thing.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn, '%m%d%Y') As FormattedDate FROM <table>;
```

Here is [an example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8a95c/1) I made using SQLFiddle.